# change Mysqli to sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am new to PHP and need to modify some code in order to compile with my Microsoft SQL Server. The original code is like this. I downloaded it from usercake

```
<?php
/*
UserCake Version: 2.0.2
http://usercake.com
*/

//Database Information
$db_host = "localhost"; //Host address (most likely localhost)
$db_name = "202"; //Name of Database
$db_user = "202"; //Name of database user
$db_pass = "password"; //Password for database user
$db_table_prefix = "uc_";

GLOBAL $errors;
GLOBAL $successes;

$errors = array();
$successes = array();

/* Create a new mysqli object with database connection parameters */
 $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name); 
GLOBAL $mysqli;

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
exit();
}

//Direct to install directory, if it exists
if(is_dir("install/"))
{
header("Location: install/");
die();

}

?>
```

I already installed sqlsrv and tested the link. It works with my database. Then I changed the code to this:

```
<?php

//Database Information
$server = "servername";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"databasename","UID"=>"xxxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxxx" );
$db_table_prefix = "uc_";

GLOBAL $errors;
GLOBAL $successes;

$errors = array();
$successes = array();

/* Create a new sqlsrv object with database connection parameters */

$mssqlsrv = new sqlsrv($server, $connectionInfo);
GLOBAL $mssqlsrv;

if(sqlsrv_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Connection Failed: " . sqlsrv_connect_errno();
  exit();
}

//Direct to install directory, if it exists
if(is_dir("install/"))
{
  header("Location: install/");
  die();
}

?>
```

I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'mssql' not found in

I think this line is the problem:

> $mssqlsrv = new sqlsrv($server, $connectionInfo);

But I do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use PDO in this case: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

You can create a DSN connection to SQL Server

```
$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=servername;Database=databasename"

$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
   $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The information to connect to SQL server is available here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php